# Multiple replaces on a column in an AWS Quicksight dataset

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I'm very new to AWS Quicksight and I'm trying to do multiple replaces on a column in a dataset. I thought that something like this calculated field would work:

`replace(replace({Registered Owner}, 'LIMITED', 'Ltd'),{Registered Owner},'kft', 'Ltd')`

But it doesn't look like you can nest Replace statements.

Any one can assist on how i might achieve this?

Regards,
Mark

Comment: Replace should take 3 parameters but your outer replace has four. Please share some example in form of current and desired output value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using nested replace -

```
replace(replace(replace({Email}, '@','ATTHERATE'),'.com','.org'),'email','quicksight')
```

Will result into following -

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i needed! I just wasn't clear on the syntax for doing multiple replaces